# Перевести код командной строки в тело кода python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Есть следующая команда, которая работает напрямую через командную стоку:

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist.txt -c copy output_1.mp4

(она объединяет видеофайлы без кодирования)

Так же есть код на python который создает эти самые видео.
Как выполнить код для командной строки в теле самого скрипта python?

Comment: @Интик честно говоря, я там ничего не понял.
Если объясните на примере моей команды - буду очень благодарен

Comment: увы я с телефона. посмотрите тут https://pythononline.ru/osnovy/sistemnye-komandy-s-pomoschyu-python-os-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Вызовите [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). Например:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist.txt -c copy output_1.mp4')
```

Интерпретатор Python вызовет команду и дождётся её завершения. Это проще всего.

**2.** Используйте пакет который вызывает ffmpeg из Python минуя командную строку. Например [kkroening/ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте  [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)
Он позволяет выполнять команды в shell и возвращает результат или ошибку.